# Match an image from a set of images : Combine traditional Computer vision + Deep Learning/CNN

Tags: opencv, image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning

In the application I am developing, I have about 5000 product label images.(One label per product).

One functionality of my application is that user can take a picture using his camera and get a possible match(es) against the product labels registered the system.

Since initially, my system only has one sample per product, I decided to go with traditional Computer Vision techniques. I managed to implement this using Feature extraction and Descriptor matching.(using OpenCV SIFT and FLANN techniques referring this: https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp)

Now I am thinking how to improve the accuracy by combining with CNN or Deep Learning techniques since when users approve matches, it gradually add more label samples for a product.

Is it possible to build a hybrid image matching system combining Computer Vision techniques and CNN/Deep Learning techniques?

Are there any similar services already available as services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn more about Distance Metrics Learning (DML). There is a lot of information on the internet, but briefly:

1. You must get embeddings (vector representation) for each image from your base (e.g. get feature vector from last convolutional layer of one of the modern CNN's (Inception, VGG, ResNet, DenseNet))
2. Then, when you get new image, you should create vector representation of the current image and find the closest vector from your base (by Euclidean distance, for example)

This topic is quite complicated, so study it carefully :)
Have a luck!